# Convert calendar String to Calendar Object in java

Tags: java, parsing, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I wan't to convert a string Calendar Object (calendar.toString()) to calendar object.
I tried this solution but it show in console the date of the day '12-05-2017' not '02-02-2017'

String calendar object format:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1485993600000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Casablanca",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=102,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Africa/Casablanca,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=10800000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=5,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=33,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

```
             Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
             calendar.setTime(new Date("2017/02/02"));
             System.out.println("calendar : "+calendar.getTime());
             try {
                 GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
                 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                 System.out.println("calendar : "+calendar.getTime());
                 gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(calendar.toString()));
                 System.out.println("tme zone : "+gc.getTimeZone());
                 System.out.println("calendar : "+calendar.getTime());
                 System.out.println("calendar : "+calendar.toString());
                 System.out.println(formatter.format(gc.getTime()));
             }
             catch(Exception e) {
                 //If exception, return server TimeStamp
             }
```

Any help please

Comment: Tried what solution?  You haven't posted any code.

Comment: Ah, no. I'd consider storing the time (long) and timezone information, maybe formatting into a `String`, but I'd not consider trying to parse the `toString` value from `Calendar` ... I'd also suggest having a look at the new Java Time API, as it supports and number of ISO formats out of the box

Comment: @azurefrog I added the code to my post

Comment: First trouble is `Calendar` is an abstract class, `GregorianCalendar` being the most widely used subclass. If you only know you have a `Calendar` object, you may have an instance of a different subclass with a completely different `toString` method. You are calling `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()`, but this is a call to `Calendar.getInstance()` and doesn’t guarantee a `GregorianCalendar` instance.

Comment: I know this is an oversimplified answer: Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `GreforianCalendar`. `LocalDate.parse()` will readily parse the string from `LocalDate.toString()`.

Comment: My feeling it can be done with `GregorianCalendar`, or at least you can come close, but it will take much parsing work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

If that were me, I’d look at all the setters of both `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` and see if I thought I could extract the values needed for the setters from the string. “time=1485993600000” should give you the most important information, the time, and you can feed it into `setTimeInMillis()`. You ought to be able to get a time zone out of “Africa/Casablanca”. And so forth. You can probably use regular expressions for extracting the fields from the string.

You’d probably have to live with not covering all cases. Your particular `GregorianCalendar` seems to contain a `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo` and a `java.util.SimpleTimeZone`; I don’t know whether that is always the case nor what other possibilities there are.

The strict test of your attempt is easy: just call `toString()` again on your newly constructed instance and see if you get the same string. The difficulty comes if you accept some differences and you need to determine whether the actual differences lie within what you have decided to accept.

Or really, I wouldn’t want to bother if I could avoid it. I’d see if I could find an easier task or an easier way to obtain what you are really trying to obtain. As I already said in a comment, one may use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `GregorianCalendar`. `LocalDate.parse()` will readily parse the string from `LocalDate.toString()`, and the problem is solved. Just to give one example of another way to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have two separate `GregorianCalendar` objects - one called `calendar` and one called `gc`.  You're setting one calendar object to the date that you want, then printing out the other one.

Comment: Sorry, @OleV.V. I guess I overreacted.  I still believe the crux of the matter is that he assigned a value to `calendar` then printed `gc`, expecting his value to magically have transferred from one object to the other - which is an issue that your answer never addressed.  Your answer does, however, contain some excellent other information, and it was clearly useful in leading OP to the correct answer.  My apologies again for my earlier comment.

Comment: No hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ole , I finally found the solution and it works.

```
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();;
             calendar.setTime(new Date("2017/02/02"));
             String[] ds = calendar.toString().split("=");
             String[] ds2 = ds[1].split(",");
             try {
                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();;
                 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                 cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.valueOf(ds2[0]));
                 System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
             }
             catch(Exception e) {

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using terrible old classes that are now supplanted by the much superior java.time classes.

Instantiate a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-02-02" ) ;
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-02-02

For other formats use the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> 02-02-2017

Your Question is not clear. If the problem is that your code is being handed a `GregorianCalendar` object, convert it to `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
if( myCalendar instanceOf GregorianCalendar ) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = myCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ;
}
```

Extract the date-only value you desire, as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).